# JACK(Java Android Compiler Kit) letter bug

Tags: java, android, gradle, jack

> --Android Studio 2.2.2
>
> --Windows 10 Home Single Language 64 bit Turkish
>
> --Nougat 7.1.1(Tested on Marshmallow and Nougat 7.0 aswell)
>
> --Build Tools version 25
>
> --Android Gradle Plugin Version 2.2.2
>
> --Tried with gradle 2.14.1 and 3.2-rc2 too

Just added these lines to my **app level build.gradle**

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**Error messages:**

```
Error:com.android.sched.util.config.PropertyIdException: Property 'jack.import.type.policy' (in -D option): The value must be {keep-fırst,faıl} (case insensitive) but is 'keep-first'


Error:com.android.sched.util.codec.ParsingException: The value must be {keep-fırst,faıl} (case insensitive) but is 'keep-first'

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.jack.api.v01.ConfigurationException: Property 'jack.import.type.policy' (in -D option): The value must be {keep-fırst,faıl} (case insensitive) but is 'keep-first'
```

> ****************** UPDATE *****************
>
> Jack is no longer needed newer versions of Android Studio including 2.4
>
> Read change log : >https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html

Answer (score 0):

**A tricky solution that i made:**

Created **run configurations** for all jack related tasks in gradle (almost 9), and update **VM Options** part with **-Duser.language=en**

starts from

**--transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug**

and ends with

**--transformJackWithJackForRelease**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to  resolved this problem You must change your system language in English.Good working all of you